# Use a query that takes parameters in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a functioning program that reads from a DB and inputs it into a flat file. I'm using Spring batch for these 
I want be able to choose the parameters for my query. How can I do that.

My xml look something like this:

```
<bean id="databaseitemreader" class="JdbcursorItemReader">
<property name = "datasource"  <ref = ...>
<property name = sql value= "Select fname , lname , address from tbl_student"/>
```

```
Item file writer stuff .....
```

(This one does not need any change)

I want to be be able to pass dynamic parameters to my query that is stored in the xml file. example: 
    where id = 1234  and current = 'Y' without being hard coded

To map the values I am currently using the rowMapper interface

Comment: Can you elaborate on the business flow here? 
Is the sql-file is nested withing the xml reading i.e.
For each element in xml
do read from db where  id =element.id  and element.current=y
write result to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section in the Spring Batch Document http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#late-binding explains how parameter can be passed to the spring batch job.
As to how you extract those parameters from the XML - that would something you would do outside the job - depending on how you are starting up the Job.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a custom reader composed by one XML and one JDBC readers.
For every node read from XML prepare an inner JDBC reader with correct sql query and delegate `ItemReader.read()` to `JDBCItemReader.read()` until exhausts; move to next XML node and continue until XML reader is terminated.
Remember to register streams (or implements `ItemStream` in custom reader and manage `ItemStream'` methods according).